# R. Recode columns based on values of other 2 columns that have different levels

Tags: r, dataframe, recode

I have a data frame with 10000 rows and 1000 columns that looks like this:

```
ID    a0    a1    V1    V2    V3
rs1   G     A     0     0     1
rs2   C     T     1     0     0
rs3   T     C     0     1     1
```

a0 and a1 can be A, T, C or G, and indicate whether the other columns are 0 or 1. For instance, in the second row, a0 = G and a1 = A, so V1 = 0 (G), V2 = 0 (G) and V3 = 1 (A). I expect an output data frame like this:

```
ID    a0    a1    V1    V2    V3
rs1   G     A     G     G     A
rs2   C     T     T     C     C
rs3   T     C     T     C     C
```

Many thanks

Comment: I just edited it, @RonakShah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` and `ifelse` to perform the replacement.

```
dat[, -(1:3)] <- lapply(dat[, -(1:3)], function(x){
  x <- ifelse(x == 0, dat[, 2], dat[, 3])
  return(x)
})

dat
#    ID a0 a1 V1 V2 V3
# 1 rs1  G  A  G  G  A
# 2 rs2  C  T  T  C  C
# 3 rs3  T  C  T  C  C
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID    a0    a1    V1    V2    V3
rs1   G     A     0     0     1
rs2   C     T     1     0     0
rs3   T     C     0     1     1",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Excellent !. Thanks very much @www !!

Answer (score 3):

Matrix indexing to the rescue, after setting `t`ar`g`e`t` and `s`ou`rc`e variables:

```
tgt <- c("V1","V2","V3")
src <- c("a0","a1")
dat[tgt] <- dat[src][cbind(seq_len(nrow(dat)), unlist(dat[tgt]+1))]

#   ID a0 a1 V1 V2 V3
#1 rs1  G  A  G  G  A
#2 rs2  C  T  T  C  C
#3 rs3  T  C  T  C  C
```

Comment: Initially, I was thinking about the row/column indexing.  Nice

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `case_when` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate_at(vars(matches("^V\\d+")), funs(case_when(!. ~ df1$a0, TRUE ~ df1$a1)))
#   ID a0 a1 V1 V2 V3
#1 rs1  G  A  G  G  A
#2 rs2  C  T  T  C  C
#3 rs3  T  C  T  C  C
```